# onBackpressed() method keeping me awake all night

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I can not navigate from page B to page A using onBackpressed() (hardware button) its just exit the whole program. :( been trying different codes for 7 days and nights now. Please can someone help the newby.

I have declared the parent activity name inside Manifest file

```
        <activity android:name="lk.ceesl.engteachersl.Nounintro"
          android:parentActivityName="lk.ceesl.engteachersl.MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="lk.ceesl.engteachersl.MainActivity" />

        </activity>
```

Then I wrote the codes in MainActivity.java to override the onBackpressed() method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

  moveTaskToBack(true);

}
```

now its just closes the app and runs in the background when i press hardware back button. please give me a solution for the most essential part of my app which is navigating with HW back button (NOT action bar backbutton please). thank you so so much in advance.

Comment: How do you go from MainActivity to Nounintro activity ?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_nounintro);

Comment: @FernandoFrancis; That's not launching an activity, that's setting a layout for your activity. You must have something like `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Nounintro.class));` in your mainactivity somewhere

Comment: You are a star and your answer is on point. I am replacing this code with setContentview() to properly launch my Nounintro activity. will post result in a sec. Thank you for saving me.

Comment: It works really well. Top man. I love Stack overflow !.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a sample project for you . Just to navigate through one activity to another .

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.surroundapps.backbutton.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to Second Activity"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
}
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.shuvro.backbutton">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Hope it will help you to understand how to navigate through activity

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends by the intent flag you used to launch activity B.
Theorically if you launch it correctly you don't need to override onBackPressed, and I think the metadata PARENT_ACTIVITY is not necessary.

Please post the code you use to launch activity B from activity A and eventually the content of moveTaskToBack method.

Comment: please forget about moveTaskback(). i just put it without actually knowing what it is. I use the code to launch activity B from activity A by calling a onClick method of a Image button. and the code is to launch B is setContentView(R.layout.activity_nounintro);

Comment: and page A launch Single Top    page B launch not specified

Comment: Please tell me how to launch the activity B correctly so i can always use the DEFAULT ONBACKPRESSED() METHOD as you said. that is what i need for my simple learning app

Comment: Thank you I got the answer. Really appreciate your help though.

Comment: it seems you are not launching activity B, but only changing layout. Use startActivity method. You can find it in Intent documentation on android guides

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to implement Up Navigation. Please refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)